# API ETIM return "Authentication Failed"

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, oauth, postman

I try to use the API of ETIM : https://etimapi.etim-international.com/swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=V2

So, request a client_id/client_secret from this https://etimapi.etim-international.com/ and received

I try to get a new access token by postman, it's said "Authentication Failed".

[image]

If anyone knows why this doesn't work, I'd love to know

If anyone understands how I should also generate the requests, for example

POST
/api/v2/Class/Search
Get a list of all classes that meet the input filters.

I would like him to explain to me how he did it. I'm pulling out what little hair I have left

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Acces Token Url

You're using:
https://etimauth.etim-international.com

The correct one:
https://etimauth.etim-international.com/connect/token